# Spring - get Method for a given request in Interceptor/Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, reflection, annotations

Various `@RequestMapping` methods inside my `@Controller` classes have custom annotations that I want to analyze at runtime.

E.g:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bla")
@RequireCommunityLevel("...")
@AnotherCustomAnnotation(value = "...")
public class FakeController {

    // ...
    @RequireScore(level = Score.Platinum, score = 8500)
    @RequestMapping("/blabla")
    @AnotherCustomAnnotation(value = "...")
    public DTOResponse<MySpecialModel> getMySpecialModels() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

When I receive a request in my custom `Interceptor` and `Filter` classes, I want to analyze which `Method` the request is going to call.

I have worked in the past with custom frameworks based on `Javax Servlet` and `Jetty` and often implemented some kind of **method-registry** one could interrogate.

For example:

```
public class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Inject
    private MyMethodRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // get the request path
        final String path = getPath(request); 

        final Method m = this.registry.getMethodForPath(path);

        // that's what I mean to do
        if (m.getAnnotation(RequireScore.class) != null) { ... }

        if (m.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(AnotherCustomAnnotation.class != null) { ... }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a similar way in `Spring`, possibly a built-in utility to analyze at runtime the `Annotation`'s on my `@RequestMapping` methods. All of this should happen within my Interceptor/Filter.

Comment: If you use an `HandlerInterceptor` you already have the desired handler.

Comment: @M.Deinum alright, you mean the `handler` object passed as parameter in `preHandle` ?

Comment: That is the one yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M.Deinum advised in the comments you can get the `Handler` as parameter in your `Interceptor`.

I have also found [this tutorial](http://www.myjavarecipes.com/tag/how-to-access-method-level-annotation-in-spring-interceptor/) that explains exactly what I needed.

In `HandlerInterceptor::preHandle`

```
final HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler; // the last parameter
final Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();

// check for annotations
```