# Spring AOP & HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-rest

I am working on an annotation that will be sending some audit events to the other microservice. 
Say, I am creating an entity and I have a method `add` on my Rest controller.

```
@PostMapping
@Audit
public ResponseEntity<EntityDTO> add(EntityDTO entity){
...
}
```

I have an appropriate Aspect defined, that is associated with the `@Audit` annotation.

But here is a trick, the nature of an audit event dictates that I need to extract some metadata from the `HttpServletRequest` itself.

And I do not want to modify my signature by adding (or replacing my only argument) `HttpServletRequest` object.

How can I pass `HttpServletRequest` into my aspect? Is there some elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using spring MVC, consider Spring MVC interceptors instead of "generic" aspects.
These are natively supported by Spring MVC and can provide access to both the handler and `HttpServletRequest` object

See [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) for using the interceptors and general configuration

See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113283/spring-get-method-for-a-given-request-in-interceptor-filter) for some information about the handler

```
final HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler; // this is what you'll get in the methods of the interceptor in the form of Object
final Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
```

Comment: the thing is that I want also to pass some extra data through that annotation, like the type of action.

can interceptor work in pair with annotation?

Comment: Yes, sure. In the interceptor you'll "introspect" the handler - will read the annotation parameters by reflection from the "Method" that I've added in the code snippet.

Comment: Interceptor is a good idea. But I have a situation: I want to log the request data(post) and response data during a `http request`.  Interceptor seems only can log request data. How to record the controller result? Thanks

Comment: There are also postHandle and afterCompletion methods in the interceptor - read about them, you're probably trying to log from preHandle?

Answer (score 0):

Following is how it can be done with Spring AOP .

Example annotation.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface Audit {
    String detail();
}
```

And the corresponding aspect

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AuditAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(audit) && within(com.package.web.controller..*)")
    public Object audit(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Audit audit) throws Throwable {
        // Get the annotation detail
        String detail = audit.detail();
        Object obj = null;
        //Get the HttpServletRequest currently bound to the thread.
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();
        try {
            // audit code
            System.out.println(detail);
            System.out.println(request.getContextPath());
            obj = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log Exception;
        }
        // audit code
        return obj;
    }
}
```

NB : Op has accepted interceptor based answer. This answer is to demonstrate the Spring AOP code to achieve the requirement.

Hope this helps

Comment: [RequestContextHolder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java) uses `ThreadLocal` . [RequestContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) : It is a Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound RequestAttributes object